# Was it a Sabbath the Lord's day in Revelation 1:10?

Tags: prophecy, revelation

Revelation 1:10

> ***I was in the Spirit on the Lord's day***, and I heard behind me a loud voice like a trumpet

I have read some comments from the SDA church which specify that the Lord's day is actually the Sabbath day.Found these comments on the SDA bible Revelation 1  which have EGW comments (7BC995:8).

How can we understand these comments?

Answer (score 1):

Biblically speaking the matter should be clear without the aid of commentaries.  Consider Jesus' own words:

> And he said unto them, The sabbath was made for man, and not man for
> the sabbath: Therefore the Son of man is Lord also of the sabbath.
> (Mark 2:27-28, KJV)

This shows Jesus as having made the claim that he was the Lord of the Sabbath, i.e. that the Sabbath was "the Lord's day."  John, who was so close to Jesus, would have remembered this and used it to tell his readers which day it was when the revelation had come to him.

The Sabbath has always been claimed by our Lord as His day.

> Speak thou also unto the children of Israel, saying, Verily **my
> sabbaths** ye shall keep: for it is a sign between me and you throughout
> your generations; **that ye may know that I am the LORD that doth
> sanctify you.** (Exodus 31:13, KJV)
>
> Ye shall keep **my sabbaths**, and reverence my sanctuary: I am the LORD.
> (Leviticus 19:30 & Leviticus 26:2, KJV)

And this truth is repeated multiple times in the Gospels.

> For the Son of man is Lord even of the sabbath day. (Matthew 12:8,
> KJV)
>
> And he said unto them, That the Son of man is Lord also of the
> sabbath. (Luke 6:5, KJV)

Comment: Why not put this answer in the other place of which it is a duplicate.  It might attract more upvotes.

Comment: I don't understand all the rules here, perhaps, but does one just _repeat_ an answer via copy/paste?  Most sites would not be desirous of this sort of repetition.

Comment: You could do either.